# Locations returned by HTTP 302 redirects do not appear in browser history?

Tags: http, redirect, browser

I'm working on an internal application used for reviewing user-generated content.

When a user visits the application, they are 302 redirected to `?page=X` (where X is the next page which needs to be reviewed). After the have reviewed the page, they click a link to `?next`, to which the server responds with another 302 redirect to the next page that needs reviewing (for example, `?page=Y`):

- *clicks* `?next` -- 302 --> `?page=X`
- *clicks* `?next` -- 302 --> `?page=Y`
- *clicks* `?next` -- 302 --> `?page=Z`

The problem is that these pages don't appear in the browser's history. For example, if the user sees page `X`, then page `Y`, then page `Z`, pages `Y` and `Z` will not appear in the history (ex, if the user presses the back button, they will be taken to page `X`).

I've got a video demonstrating the problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_-NfZzZ700

How can I make sure that all the pages displayed also appear in the browser's history?

I have tried using an HTTP 303 redirect too, and that has the same effect.

(note: I realize that I could include a link to the next page in each page, as multiple reviewers may be working at the same time)

This is the code used in the video:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)
x = [1]

@app.route("/")
def index():
    page = request.args.get("page")
    if not page:
        return redirect("?page=%s" %(x[0], ))
    x[0] += 1
    return """
        <html>
            <title>%s</title>
            <body>
                <p>page: %s</p>
                <a href="?next">go to next page</a>
            </body>
        </html>
    """ %(page, page)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Chrome is using the unredirected URL for purposes of history comparisons. Since the unredirected URLs are the same ("?next"), no entry is added. The behavior kind of makes sense because the non-redirected URL is what the user intended to follow, and you haven't said that the change is permanent. Still, this could be considered a browser bug (FF25 behaves as expected); see [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2801).

So, while it looks like there's no real "solution," there is at least a workaround: if you make sure that the "next" url is always unique (for example, by appending a timestamp query param), each item will get its own entry in the history list. Of course, depending on how your real app works (HTML caching, etc.), this may not be an option /:

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark but an [HTTP 303](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) seems like what you want instead.